# JQuery UI calculate sizing of content inside dialog to avoid scroll bars in the dialog

Tags: jquery, layout, resize

I'm putting some content inside a JQuery UI dialog. The HTML is as follows:

```
<div id="dialog">
  <div id="content">

    <div id="scrollable">

      <div id="data">
        <ul>
        <li/>
        <li/>
         ....
       </ul>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div id="footer">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the JQuery code is sth like:

```
$('#dialog').dialog({
  width : 500,
  height: 300
})
```

As you see, the sizing that is important to me is the sizing of the main container, the dialog. I want the content to feet inside the dialog without scrollbars in the dialog. The content has two pieces, the data itself that always has a vertical scroll bar and a footer that is always visible (this part has already been [solved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7504918/how-to-create-a-div-with-vertical-scrollable-contents-and-fixed-footer-which-is-a))
The solution should resize the content div. I have tried several calculations taking into account that the available height inside the dialog is:

```
var height=$('#dialog').height()-$('.ui-dialog-titlebar').height();
var dataHeight = height-$('#footer').height();
```

Comment: Seems I found a perfect fit as long as the dialog is not resizable. In this case the icon for resizing breaks everything. I set the width and height of #content to this (widget is the dialog):

> var width =$('.ui-dialog-titlebar', widget.element).width();

> var height = widget.element.height() - $('.ui-dialog-titlebar', widget.element).height();

Comment: why don't you set `height: auto;` to `#scrollable` or whatever div where the scrollbar is ? With CSS indeed, or `$("#scrollable").css({ 'height': 'auto' });` if you can't access the CSS file.